# Iterate through every possible range of list

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a function that takes in a list, and iterates through every possible range for example:

```
example = [1,2,3,4] 

for i in a_list[i:j++]:
    # do something
```

**iterates through ranges between 0:j++**

- [1,2]
- [1,2,3]
- [1,2,3,4]

**and then it iterates through ranges between 1:j++**

- [2,3]
- [2,3,4]

**and then it iterates through ranges between 2:j++**

- [3,4]

And so on...

Comment: That's literally a nested for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nested loops:

```
>>> example = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in range(len(example)):
...     for j in range(i, len(example)):
...         print(example[i:j+1])
...
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3]
[3, 4]
[4]
```

Comment: You could improve this with descriptive variable names: `n = len(example); for start in range(n): for end in range(start, n)`. Or `start_pos` and `end_pos` if you want to be explicit.